# SQL Server varbinary trailing 0 interpretation

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [sql_table1] ([c0] varbinary(25) NOT NULL primary key) 
go

insert into sql_table1 values (0x3200),(0x32);
go
```

I get

> Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.sql_table'. The duplicate
>   key value is (0x32).

Why? `0x32` does not equal `0x3200`

Comment: SQL Server pads varbinary strings of differing lengths with hex zeros for comparison as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx.

Comment: `SELECT (CASE WHEN 0x32 = 0x3200 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` prints `1` but `SELECT (CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, 0x32)  = CONVERT(int,0x3200) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` prints `0`. See the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It gets right padded.  `BINARY` data gets tricky when you try to specify what should normally be equivalent numerically hex values.  If you try this it will work:

```
insert into #sql_table1 values (0x32),(CAST(50 as VARBINARY(25)));
-- inserts 0x00000032
-- and     0x32
```

But these are numerically equivalent.  Generally speaking, it's a bad idea to have a `BINARY` column of any sort be a primary key or try to put a unique index on it (moreso than a `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` column) - any application that inserts into it is going to almost certainly be `CAST`ing from some native format/representation to binary, but there's no guarantee that that `CAST` actually works in a unique manner in either direction - did the application insert the value `50` (`= 0x32`), or did it try to insert the literal `0x32`, or did it try to insert the ASCII value of `2` (`= 0x32`), or did it insert the first byte(s) of something else....?   If one app submits `0x32` and another `0x0032` are they the same or different (SQL Server says different - see below)?

The bottom line is that SQL Server is going to behave unusually if you try to compare binary columns flat out without some context.  What will work is comparing binary data using `BINARY_CHECKSUM`

```
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x32)  -- 50
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x320) -- 16! -- it's treating this as having a different number or ordering of bytes
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x3200) -- 50
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x32000) -- 16
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x0032) -- 50
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x00032) -- 50
SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(0x000000000032)  -- 50
```

but again, this only helps you see that the hexidecimal represenation of the binary data isn't going to work exactly the way it would seem.  The point is, your primary key is going to be based on the `BINARY_CHECKSUM`s of the data instead of any particular format/representation of the data.  Normally that's a good thing, but with binary data (and padding) it becomes a lot trickier.  Even then, in my example above the `BINARY_CHECKSUM` of both columns will be exactly the same (`SELECT BINARY_CHECKSUM(c0) FROM sql_table1` will output `50` for both rows).  Weird - a little further testing is showing that any different number of leading 0s that fit into the column length will bypass the unique check even though the checksum is the same (e.g. `VALUES (0x32), (0x032), (0x0032)` etc.).

This only gets worse if you start throwing different versions of SQL Server into the mix (per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx)).

What you should do for PK/Unique design on a table is figure out what context will make sense of this data - an order number, a file reference, a timestamp, a device ID, some other business or logical identifier, etc....  If nothing else, pseudokey it with an `IDENTITY` column.